# Can't get removeChild to work correctly

Tags: javascript, html

Excuse the primitive question. I want to use removeChild to remove a row dynamically in an HTML table. I followed the tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) and still does not work with me. Here is a sample of what I'm doing. The error I get is:

```
NotFoundError: Node was not found
```

The code and script:

```js
var currentRow=document.getElementById("row-2");
var table = document.getElementById("data-table");
table.removeChild(currentRow);
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
      </head>
    
      <body id="body">
        <table align="center" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="data-table" border=1 class="data-table">
          <tr id="head" class="head">
            <td class="head">A</td>
            <td class="head">B</td>
            <td class="head">C</td>
          </tr>
    
           <tr id="row-1" class="head">
            <td class="head" id="col1-1">A1</td>
            <td class="head" id="col2-1">B1</td>
            <td class="head" id="col3-1">C1</td>
          </tr>
       
       <tr id="row-2" class="head">
            <td class="head" id="col1-2">A2</td>
            <td class="head" id="col2-2">B2</td>
            <td class="head" id="col3-2">C2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Always use debugging like `console.log(table.children);` first

Comment: Use `currentRow.parentNode.removeChild(currentRow);` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern browser wraps `tr` in `tbody` element, thus your code didn't worked.

You can use [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) to get a reference to `tbody` then you can remove it.

```js
var currentRow = document.getElementById("row-2");
currentRow.parentNode.removeChild(currentRow);
```

```html
<table align="center" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="data-table" border=1 class="data-table">
  <tr id="head" class="head">
    <td class="head">A</td>
    <td class="head">B</td>
    <td class="head">C</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="row-1" class="head">
    <td class="head" id="col1-1">A1</td>
    <td class="head" id="col2-1">B1</td>
    <td class="head" id="col3-1">C1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="row-2" class="head">
    <td class="head" id="col1-2">A2</td>
    <td class="head" id="col2-2">B2</td>
    <td class="head" id="col3-2">C2</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Table rows are not children of the `<table>` element. Even if there's no `<tbody>` in the markup, the DOM is built as if there were:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
```

Thus, you need to look for the `<tbody>` parent of the row, and remove it from that.

In general, there's no need to explicitly find an element's parent in order to remove the element from the DOM, because all elements have a `.parent` property referring to the parent. Thus, you can always use

```
someElement.parent.removeChild(someElement)
```

to remove `someElement`. In your case:

```
currentRow = document.getElementById("row-2");
currentRow.parent.removeChild(currentRow);
```

Note that in addition to `<tbody>`, there are `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` table sections available. The only one that'll be implicitly added however is `<tbody>`.

Comment: Wow. When did you even answer this? `:O`

Comment: While this is a good explanation of the problem, this answer would be improved by adding the JavaScript which would actually remove the desired row.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, even though your code has:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="data-table" border=1 class="data-table">
  <tr id="head" class="head">
    <td class="head">A</td>
    <td class="head">B</td>
    <td class="head">C</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="row-1" class="head">
    <td class="head" id="col1-1">A1</td>
    <td class="head" id="col2-1">B1</td>
    <td class="head" id="col3-1">C1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="row-2" class="head">
    <td class="head" id="col1-2">A2</td>
    <td class="head" id="col2-2">B2</td>
    <td class="head" id="col3-2">C2</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<script>
  var currentRow=document.getElementById("row-2");
  var table = document.getElementById("data-table");
  table.removeChild(currentRow);
</script>
```

In real rendering, it gets transformed with `<tbody>`. Use Inspect Element to check. In simple way, you can do:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="data-table" border=1 class="data-table">
  <tr id="head" class="head">
    <td class="head">A</td>
    <td class="head">B</td>
    <td class="head">C</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="row-1" class="head">
    <td class="head" id="col1-1">A1</td>
    <td class="head" id="col2-1">B1</td>
    <td class="head" id="col3-1">C1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="row-2" class="head">
    <td class="head" id="col1-2">A2</td>
    <td class="head" id="col2-2">B2</td>
    <td class="head" id="col3-2">C2</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<script>
  var currentRow = document.getElementById("row-2");
  currentRow.parentNode.removeChild(currentRow);
</script>
```

```html
<table align="center" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="data-table" border=1 class="data-table">
  <tr id="head" class="head">
    <td class="head">A</td>
    <td class="head">B</td>
    <td class="head">C</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="row-1" class="head">
    <td class="head" id="col1-1">A1</td>
    <td class="head" id="col2-1">B1</td>
    <td class="head" id="col3-1">C1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="row-2" class="head">
    <td class="head" id="col1-2">A2</td>
    <td class="head" id="col2-2">B2</td>
    <td class="head" id="col3-2">C2</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<script>
  var currentRow = document.getElementById("row-2");
  currentRow.parentNode.removeChild(currentRow);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `removeChild` from a parent.

Luckily, there's a reference to the parent on every element, so you can use that:

```
var currentRow = document.getElementById("row-2");
currentRow.parentNode.removeChild(currentRow);
```

This saves some extra code and is easy to read.